# Registered users public listing showing only the selected fields by each user

Tags: user, custom-field, geolocation

I'm looking to display a map (google map or other) together with a list of all our registered Joomla 3.9.x users, their addresses and extra information are stored using Joomla user custom fields.

What we would like to accomplish is to allow each user to mark a checkbox for the fields they would like to display publicly (to non-registered users), for example some users might want to display their full address, others might want to display just their city and state but not their full address, and others might want to display even their email address, or nothing but their handle.

I've been checking multiple contact, listing and directory components (paid and free) but I haven't been able to find one that lists the ability for the users to choose what they want to make public or not.

Does anyone know of an extension or component that would allow this functionality out of the box?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback/support.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: you could use Custom Fields + Alternative Template Override + Advanced Custom Fields for geographic map.

**Custom Fields**

If you are using Custom Fields to ask for all those details then you could indeed ask for a "make this info public" Custom Field for each Field (e.g. address + address_pub).

For each Custom Field switch OFF "Automatic Display". Otherwise the fields will be displayed via a core plugin. I would also check if Joomla's Search (Search via com_search and Smart Search via com_finder) won't display/find the non-public Custom Fields. Same goes for Joomla's or any non-core caching option.

**Alternative Template Override**

To display the fields in the front-end you could create an (Alternative) Template Override (= Template Override with new name). In that override you check for each Custom Field ("address") if its "make this info public" field ("address_pub") is true. If so display it, otherwise not.

Information about Template Overrides: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

**Advanced Custom Fields**

To use a Location / Maps field you could use a non-core extension **Advanced Custom Fields** that supports Google Maps, Bing Maps and OpenStreetMap (even in the free version)
https://www.tassos.gr/joomla-extensions/advanced-custom-fields